# is X^n more efficient than X^(1/n)? (n being integer)

Tags: computation-theory, processing-efficiency

I'm guessing X^n is more efficient. Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you guess that? How can you have a guess without some rationale?

Comment: That depends. What algorithms are you using?

Comment: Define "efficient".  (But in any case it's not "efficient" to calculate X^n when you need X^(1/n).)

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=y%3D2%5Ex%2C+y%3D2%5E(1%2Fx)+from+-1+to+10) answer your question?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I take it that 'X' is constant? As n grows, 2^n gets bigger rather quickly. But as n grows for 2^(1/n), it gets smaller. However, I am not too sure what algorithm gives you 2^(1/n)... The only problem with 2^(1/n) is that it starts off being very huge (infinity, actually) and shrinks over time. Again, I am curious as to what algorithm gives you 2^(1/n) or if it even exists...